# How to add metadata title, artists, etc. to songs in PHP?

Tags: php, id3, id3-tag

I have created a Youtube to mp3 script with PHP. I would like to add the ability to add metadata of the title, artists, album, etc. I have created a test PHP script, using the [id3_set_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.id3-set-tag.php)() function to add metadata to an MP3 but when I load the page it is blank and the file remains untouched.

```
<?php
$data = array(
              "title" => "Re:Start",
              "artist" => "Re:\Legion",
              "comment" => "A nice track"
             );
$result = id3_set_tag( "Test.mp3", $data, ID3_V1_0 );
if ($result === true) {
    echo "Tag successfully updated\n";
}
?>
```

Here are the **Apache/PHP** logs:

> [Mon Jun 11 17:54:39.197984 2018] [php7:error] [pid 1458] [client 127.0.0.1:51864] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function id3_set_tag() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php:7\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php on line 7

**Specs:**
Apache

PHP 7

macOS High Sierra

So my question is: How do I add song metadata to a MP3 file with PHP on Mac?

Comment: Why would this be any different on macOS than on any other platform that PHP runs on? You should check with `phpinfo()` if that function is compiled in.

Comment: @tadman Not exactly sure how to check, but went to phpinfo(), did a quick CMD - F and no results for id3. Maybe another way to do it? P.S. Nothing in `disabled_functions` either.

Comment: @tadman According to the guide [here](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/determine-if-a-php-function-is-available), it is not enabled. Not sure what to do about that.

Comment: The documentation covers [the installation procedure](http://php.net/manual/en/id3.installation.php).

Comment: @tadman I appreciate your help! Unfortunately the link seems very vague. It says I should edit a file but I am not sure where that file is.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for your help. I am installing it as we speak. Will report back after.

Comment: You might try this. It is a relatively recent tutorial, but Apple has recently restricted some directories: https://sergeyzhuk.me/2016/11/07/osx-pecl-install/

Comment: @tadman Installed from [here](https://github.com/larsbs/id3v2lib) installed successfully, although I couldn't find the file or line they were talking about in your link. But still it appears the functions is not installed.